# Java Tesseract Inaccurate Results

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I'm creating a bot that needs to be able to read numbers from my screen. The source image is very small and can't be zoomed in on. For reference, here's one of the images:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfde1.jpg)

This image is being read as 15151.

I've tried scaling the image using the following code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMxxy.png)

Here's an example of the scaled result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb8EN.jpg)

this image is being read as 1515?

I'm very new to Java and this is above my skill level, but my bot is so close to being useable, so I really want to complete it. Any suggestions of how I can improve would be greatly appreciated!

I should also mention that my console is outputting the following errors: "Warning: Parameter not found: enable_new_segsearch and Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.", however, these don't seem to be causing issues when the input image is of good quality, so I have been ignoring them.

Thank you!!